# Get Pair Value from Java Map at given index

Tags: android

Consider following java code

```
categoryMap.put(movie.getCategory(),movieList1);
Iterator it = categoryMap.entrySet().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();

    Log.d("Key", pair.getKey().toString());
    Log.d("Val5", pair.getValue(5).toString());
```

`pair.getValue()` returns a `List` of 7 and I need to get the value at index 5, but `pair.getValue()` does not accept parameters.

What could I do to get the value I need?

Comment: `pair.getValue().get(5)` should work, and if you will only use the map here and always need the value at 5 do `categoryMap.put(movie.getCategory(),movieList1.get(5))` so you can call `pair.getValue()` directly

Comment: Thank u for your answer. Seems I made a little mistake stating that movieList1 is an ArrayList. In fact it's a List object so that's why pair.getValue().get() is not an option in the intellisense